# Import a int to a another class

Tags: c#, int

I have 2 different classes.

1 class where you start and choose your class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean Choose = false;
        string Input;
        int Tactic = 0, Defend = 0, Attack = 0;
        MenuTacticus HubTacticus = new MenuTacticus();

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the PanaKnockOut Alpha V.");
        Console.WriteLine("There are three classes you can choose: Tacticus, Attacker, Defender \nEnter the name of the class to choose the class. \nFor more info about the classes enter ?");
        while (Choose == false){
            Console.WriteLine("What do you choose?");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Input = (Console.ReadLine());
            Input.ToLower();
            switch (Input)
            {
                case "tacticus":
                    Choose = true;
                    Tactic = 60;
                    Defend = 30;
                    Attack = 30;
                    HubTacticus.HubTacticus();
                    break;
                case "attacker":
                    Tactic = 30;
                    Defend = 30;
                    Attack = 60;
                    Choose = true;
                    break;
                case "defender":
                    Tactic = 30;
                    Defend = 60;
                    Attack = 30;
                    Choose = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("This isn't a class at this moment.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
                    break;
            } 
        }

    }
}
```

And a class where you get when you choose a class:

```
class MenuTacticus
{
    public void HubTacticus()
    {
        string Choice;
        Boolean HUB = true;
        ArenaTacticus ARENAT = new ArenaTacticus();
        //tactic from other class here 
        //defend from other class here
        //attack from other class here

        while (HUB == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Main Menu you wil come here more \n(I know it looks boring but I am a starting programmer so i can't build a interface/menu");
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do now? \nPlay a match(type: play)/Train(type: train");
            Choice = Console.ReadLine();
            Choice.ToLower();
            switch (Choice)
            {
                case "play":
                    ARENAT.ARENAT();
                    break;
                case "train":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i have a problem i don't know how i need to import the int: Tactic/Defend/Attack from the ***Programm*** class to the  ***MenuTacticus*** class.

Comment: This question takes me back, good luck to you @TomStarter, welcome to the world of coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you should use an object and pass that through to the method.  The benefit of an object is reusability and the capability to append further functionality to these properties, if need be, later on in your code (such as calculations or derived properties):

```
public class Stats
{
   public Stats(int tactic, int defend, int attack)
   {
      Tactic = tactic;
      Defend = defend;
      Attack = attack;
   }
   public int Tactic {get;private set;}
   public int Defend {get;private set;}
   public int Attack {get;private set;}
}
```

Then add a parameter to your HubTacticus method:

```
class MenuTacticus
{
    public void HubTacticus(Stats stats)
    {
        string Choice;
        Boolean HUB = true;
        ArenaTacticus ARENAT = new ArenaTacticus();
        //stats.Tactics
        //stats.Defend
        //stats.Attack

        while (HUB == true)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And then adjust your Main logic:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean Choose = false;
        string Input;
        Stats stats;
        MenuTacticus HubTacticus = new MenuTacticus();

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the PanaKnockOut Alpha V.");
        Console.WriteLine("There are three classes you can choose: Tacticus, Attacker, Defender \nEnter the name of the class to choose the class. \nFor more info about the classes enter ?");
        while (Choose == false){
            Console.WriteLine("What do you choose?");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Input = (Console.ReadLine());
            Input.ToLower();
            switch (Input)
            {
                case "tacticus":
                    Choose = true;
                    //Tactic = 60;
                    //Defend = 30;
                    //Attack = 30;
                    stats = new Stats(60,30,30);
                    HubTacticus.HubTacticus(stats);
                    break;
                case "attacker":
                    //Tactic = 30;
                    //Defend = 30;
                    //Attack = 60;
                    stats = new Stats(30,30,60);
                    Choose = true;
                    break;
                case "defender":
                    //Tactic = 30;
                    //Defend = 60;
                    //Attack = 30;
                    stats = new Stats(30,60,30);
                    Choose = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("This isn't a class at this moment.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
                    break;
            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i adjusted al the classes like you did but now i have the last problem when i choose a class (lets take Tacticus) i try to print my stats to look if it worked with: `Console.WriteLine(stats.Tactic);` when i am running the console it doesn't print anything

Comment: @TomStarter Where are you trying to call the Console.WriteLine(stats.Tactic)?

Comment: it's solved i forgot a capital letter. thx for the help it solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Add parameters to your `HubTacticus()` function:

```
public void HubTacticus(int tactic, int defend, int attack)
```

Comment: it would be nice if this was a class.

Comment: or a class that have properties, if more are added, you won't have to change the signature of the method

Comment: @DanielA.White same comment :-)

Comment: i added the parameters to my HubTacticus() function. now i tried to print them with: Console.WriteLine(Tactic); but it doesn't print anything.                    Is there something i forget?